# Maximum characters of number field data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

[image]I have a problem when I create a Data Extension where there is a numeric field. Named "CPF". 10 characters is the maximum supported in a field in the Data Extension?

I've already tried to import files and created a landing page for viewing. When I try to put more than 10 numbers in the Smart Capture the ''submit button'' simply does not work like it's locked.  What could be happening?
Landing page created: https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/gkrhyuhjfhf

I lookup in documentation, but only thing that i found is ''An integer. Decimal values are not supported". Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you provide some more details into the DE and any related scripts around the data entry? As well, can you put further explanation into 'Landing does not work'.  Is there an error? Does the number not display? Is it truncated?

Comment: The submit button in smart capture like it's locked when i put more than 10 
character in field CPF

Comment: I agree with @JohannesSchapdick - I would change this field from number to text in the DE and set your character limits there. This is also important as (judging from your comments) you want to retain the leading zeros, which is much easier via text format than in number format.

Answer (score 4):

Number values are internally INTEGER.

Therefore its range is `-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647`.
So maybe that is where your errors come from when you exceed the number range. Atleast something like that has happened to me when i had a order number configured like number but they were higher than `int_max`.

You can try to insert 2,147,483,647  (it works) and 2,147,483,648 does not. Therefore its clearly an Integer issue.

If you need to have higher number values and really need the number type you should change it to Decimal. If this range is not fitting either you should consider using text.

Comment: Hello, @Johannes Schapdick. In Brazil, we have the CPF (Individual Person Registry) where it usually has 11 numbers (only the oldest ones have smaller numbers), so the problem is reported. Example: mine is: 13672702580. I can not apply.

The problem with the decimal is that if the CPF starts with 0 the number will be removed and the result will be 10 characters. I put as text to solve, but it is not ideal.

Comment: When you want to store the real values you won't have the possibility to take a different data type than text (tbh), because the length of the ID varies and you cannot add leading zeros because you dont know how many you have to insert (example CPFs start with 00... or 000... or 0...). Which part of the "text" solution makes you think that it is not ideal?

Comment: Agreed - I would change the format of the data extension field to text and can set the char count you require there.  Especially if you require the leading 0, this will disappear when stored as a number very easily.